# Type Refinements in Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm getting an error that 'The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.' but at the start of the function I have a runtime check to ensure that `this.startedDateTime` is a number. I'm confused about why this type refinement doesn't work.

```
/* @flow */

class Transfer {
    startedDateTime: ?number;

    start() {
        this.startedDateTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    get elapsedTime(): ?number {
        if (typeof this.startedDateTime === 'number') {
            const currentDateTime: number = new Date().getTime();
            const elapsedMs: number = this.startedDateTime - currentDateTime;
            return elapsedMs;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAFQCdsA7XKAU2LAG9UwxcAXbYlqgEwBFtPCASwC2VAFxgA-GQCuwgEY0A3Oiat2LABQBKeoyZgWAC0G4AdOo7c+AkVTABeMGSpIbVHWYDmVFkNE6KkwAvqpgPixgVDgADrjc-h7aEtJyirQMBmCCUGCaLACeMVRwucamFmxWvPxUiY4OTgDksgo0TbqZWWAYcBSRGDLExFRkLO6JEq3pjs6uYO6eEYmB+lm9-VGx8VwAsrhTaTSz5eaWnDW2omAAtD1DI2MTdkHdIyxDZFvYcdz7ryE1mB3p9nDIYDBXqFgkA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that type refinements are invalidated with the first subsequent function call - `Date().getTime()` in your example.

Functions/methods aren't pure in Javascript but may perform side effects. `Date().getTime()` for example may delete `this.startedDateTime` or set it to `null`. Consequently flow invalidates your refinement to preserve type safety.

To bypass this behavior you can store the property in a constant before any function invocation:

```
/* @flow */

class Transfer {
  startedDateTime: ?number;

  start() {
    this.startedDateTime = new Date().getTime();
  }

  get elapsedTime(): ?number {
    if (typeof this.startedDateTime === 'number') {
      const startedDateTime = this.startedDateTime;
  //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      const currentDateTime: number = new Date().getTime();
      const elapsedMs: number = startedDateTime - currentDateTime;
  //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      return elapsedMs;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

[Try it](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAFQCdsA7XKAU2LAG9UwxcAXbYlqgEwBFtPCASwC2VAFxgA-GQCuwgEY0A3Oiat2LABQBKeoyZgWAC0G4AdOo7c+AkVTABeMGSpIbVHWYDmVFkNE6KkwAvqpgPixgVDgADrjc-h7aEtJyirQMBmCCUGCaLACeMVRwucamFmxWvPxUiY4OTgDksgo0TbqZWWAYcBSRlpw1tqKOhibmg9a1iUHdvf09MsTEVGQs7okSreljLm61nhGJgfpZC6xRsfFcALK422k0Y1PDdXZgALRLK2sbM3Y5llVixlmQrtg4tx7kCwKFgb4wc4ZDAYHNQsEgA)

Answer (score 1):

In your approach `startedDateTime` can be: `number`, `null` or `undefined`, because you are using [Flow Maybe Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/). You just need to say: `startedDateTime: number;`.

Here you are a [example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAFQCdsA7XKAU2LAG9UwxcAXbYlqgEwBFtPCASwC2VAFxgyAV2EAjGgG50TVuxYAKAJT1GTMCwAWg3ADpVHbnwEiqYALySqSK1S0mA5lRZDRWpUwBfZTBPFjAqHAAHXG4fV00JAH5pORodPTBBKDB1FgBPSKo4bMNjMzYLXn4qOPs7BwByFPliBu0GDKYMOAowjCliYioyFhc4iWa0hzInMBc3ULi-XQzu3vComK4AWVwJmRb7fSNTc04q61EwAFowfsHh0eq4-06hlgGyDexo7l3XwIrMDvT6SKQwGCvIIBIA).

Maybe you want to do this:

```
class Transfer {
    startedDateTime: ?number;
    start() {
        return this.startedDateTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    get elapsedTime(): ?number {
        if (typeof this.startedDateTime === 'number') {
            const currentDateTime: number = new Date().getTime();
            const elapsedMs: number = this.start() - currentDateTime;
            return elapsedMs;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```